# Print certain parameter in column with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I stumbled over a little problem, which I am not able to solve with awk in a bash script.

I do have following data file:

```
 33   1000   1.108932e-01   2.825803e+00  -9.955642e-05    0.0000e+00       0.0000e+00    8.012180e-02 4.081916e-02

 0.0000e+00   7.8557e-01   6.1128e+01   4.0468e+00  -9.9558e-05   3.8526e-02   3.1874e-03   5.1303e-01   0.0000e+00

 1.6667e-02   7.8530e-01   6.0977e+01   4.0552e+00   1.0627e-01   7.8951e-02   6.2521e-03   5.0750e-01   0.0000e+00

...
```

which has a header line with 10 elements, followed by an array with 33 rows and 9 columns.

I would like to use the data in this file to print out the forth parameter from the header line followed by the average of line 3 (i.e. `sum+=$3 / {Number of lines}`). At the moment, I try to do it like:

```
gawk '{time=FNR==1{$4};if(NR>1)sum+=$3}; time = FNR == 1{$4} END {sum=sum/(NR-1); print time " " sum}' $tmpn.data >> $tmpn.vrms
```

It works fine for the average, however, the time paramter is not correct and I only get a 0 as return. Maybe I am missing only a small thing, but, unfortunately I couldn't find anything online. What would be the best way to solve this issue.

Thanks for the help.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'NR==1 {time=$4;next} {sum+=$3} END {print time, (sum/(NR-1))}' $tmpn.data >>$tmpn.vrms
```

- `NR==1 {time=$4;next}` is a pattern-action pair:

  - Pattern (condition) `NR==1` is only true for the first input line.
  - Thus, action `{time=$4;next}` is only executed for the first line, and it stores the header's 4th field in variable `time`, then proceeds to the next record (line; `next`).
- `{sum+=$3}`, which is processed for all remaining records (i.e, the *data* records), iteratively sums up the values in the 3rd field in variable `sum`.
- `END {print time, (sum/(NR-1))}`:

  - The `END` block is executed after all input records have been processed.
  - `{print time, (sum/(NR-1))}` prints the header field and the average of the 3rd-field values, separated by the default output field separator (`OFS`), which is a space. Note that `NR` contains the total number of input records inside the `END` block.

---

**A note on your solution attempt and `awk`'s philosophy**:

- As (currently) stated, your command breaks, because you've enclosed the entire script in `{...}`.
- Generally, **`awk`'s terse elegance** comes from **a *sequence* of carefully crafted *pattern-action* pairs**.

  - A *pattern* is a condition (Boolean expression) that executes the associated *action* (a sequence of statements) only, if the condition is true.
  - Think of the pattern as the conditional part of an `if` statement with the "syntactic noise" removed, and the action as the body of that `if` statement:
    `<pattern> { <action-cmd1>; ... }` is (conceptually) short for `if (<pattern>) { <action-cmd1>; ... }`
- In a given pair, **you may either omit the action, or the pattern**:

  - If you **omit the *pattern***, the **action is *executed unconditionally*** (though the action may still not get to execute, if a previous pattern-action pair skipped further processing, such as with `next` or `exit`).
  - If you **omit the *action***, the **default action is `{ print }`**, i.e., to print the (potentially modified) current record.

    - This behavior is enables the common shorthand `1` to simply print the current record: `1` is a pattern that, in the Boolean context in which patterns are evaluated, is always true, and, in the absence of an associated action, the current record is printed by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description and explenation. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another version in awk using `getline` in `while` loop to read and detect the end of file and then output the header buffer `b` and the average:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{b=$4; while(getline==1){s+=$3;c++} print b,s/c}' data
4th 40.7386
```

It expects the `data`file to have a header line. Explained:

```
NR==1 {                  # read in the first line and ...
    b=$4                 # ... buffer the 4th field of the header 
    while(getline==1) {  # then read while there are records to read
        s+=$3            # sum up the values in the 3rd field
        c++              # count the number of values, add if($3!="") if needed
    } 
    print b, s/c         # after while output header and average
}
```